# How to add a textview below a listview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I am tying to have a layout where I have a listview at the top of my screen,  textview which is just below the listview and a button at the bottom of the screen.

This is my main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD THIS IS A DAMN TEXTVIEW"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.suudupa.customtextviews;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
            "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};
//    String[] mobileArray = {"Windows7","Max OS X"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And activity_listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

When I have a large number of items in my listview, this works perfectly however when I have a few items, the textview sticks to the top of button rather than sticking to bottom of listview.

Please help me out.

Comment: it's because of this `android:layout_gravity="top"`, instead of that use a relative layout and add the button below the listview, if you want give min height to listview

Answer (score 2):

Try to use ConstraintLayout like below example

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD THIS IS A DAMN TEXTVIEW"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobile_list" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add another layout over your listview to keep listview full height.

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="HELLO WORLD THIS IS A DAMN TEXTVIEW"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="HELLO WORLD"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

This work fine for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      >
  </ListView>
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="HELLO WORLD THIS IS A DAMN TEXTVIEW"
      android:layout_below="@+id/mobile_list"
      />
  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="HELLO WORLD"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `Relative Layout` doesn't have `Weights`?

Comment: This will make Textview go out of the screen when listview size is bigger than the screen size